# Use one template for two similar but different tasks?

Tags: django, templates

I have a `template_a.html`-- which is included in some open-sourced library and which I expect to get updates in the future.

I need a template where only small portions are different from `template_a`.
I can copy-paste and make it `template_b`, or I can use `{% if {{ request.get_full_path }} == 'some-string' %}` to differentiate what I'm using the template for.

What's the better practice here?

1. make copy and separate templates for each task.
2. use get_full_path to differentiate the task.(mainly I don't like the idea of using get_full_path, since I can change the path later, is
   there a better approach?)

Comment: How are they different? Only data changes or structure too? Are views different?

Comment: 1. They will have different style(different css), 2. They use different editor(for textarea like input) 3. their hiddenInput field has different value set.

Comment: In general it is recommended to keep things separated. Especially with what you just said about the differences I would advice you to make two templates.

Comment: even though 95% of code is same?

Comment: Sounds like you want inheritance :P

Answer (score 0):

- You can create one base template for common parts of both templates
- Define blocks for parts that are changing.
- Extend both templates from the base template and only define blocks that you want changed.
- View can use appropriate template to render response.

Reference [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Sample:

Template_base.html

```
{% block header %}
  {# something in header #}
{% endblock %}

{% block common %}
  {# something in common #}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {# filled by derived templates #}
{% endblock %}
```

Template_a.html

```
{% extends "template_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {# write your html for a.html #}
{% endblock %}
```

Template_b.html

```
{% extends "template_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {# write your html for b.html #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks rohan that makes sense. I need to slightly tweak the question though.  I'm expecting to get updates from this opensourced github (which has template_a.html).